# rails nested resource on form generates wrong json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, nested

I have a basic create form in rails for a resource (shoppingprocess) and a nested resource (processings)

```
<%= form_for(shopping_process) do |f| %>
```

....

```
<!-- SUB FORM FOR NESTED RESOURCE : PROCESSINGS -->
<%= f.fields_for :processings, @shopping_process.processings.build do |ff| %>

 <div>
 <%= ff.label :Begleiter %>
 <%= ff.select :shopping_list_id, ShoppingList.accessible_by(current_ability).map{ |sl| [sl.user.firstname, sl.id]} , {:prompt => true} %>
 </div>

 <div>
  <%= ff.label :message %>
  <%= ff.text_field :message%>
 </div>
```

that gets send to the controller that accepts the nested resource parameters 
         params.require(:shopping_process).permit(:user_id, :status, :appointed, :processed, :shopping_list_id, processings_attributes: [ :shopping_list_id, :message ])

the problem is that i get an error whenever i want to save the nested resource. when i check the log for the generated params i get this

"processings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"shopping_list_id"=>"2", "message"=>""}}

so I assume that somewhere an additional nesting happens (because of the "0"), but i dont know where and how to solve it

PS: please note that i use cancancan so my controller does NOT have a method for "new", so I need to create the nested resource within the view. The instance does not exist before, but the user has to be able to create a new instance within this form

---

UPDATE

controller:

```
params.require(:shopping_process).permit(:user_id, :status, :appointed, :processed, :shopping_list_id, processings_attributes: [ :shopping_list_id, :message ])
```

model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :processings
```

Comment: JSON is in right format. Might be error in your backend. Could you update your question showing actual error and your model and Controller method.

Comment: error i get is :   1 error prohibited this shopping_process from being saved: Processings shopping process needs to be filled

Comment: Is your params of processings_attributes meeting the validations set on Processing Model ?

Comment: just checked it and i validated that the shopping_process needs to be present but when i commented it out, it works!! Thanks a lot